# ROW COUNT in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

In mysql, I got table "a" as follow

```
ID     USERNAME        SUBJECT_ID
1      ALAN            1
2      ALAN            2
3      ALAN            3
4      ALAN            4
5      ALAN            5
6      JOHN            6
7      ALAN            7
8      JOHN            8
9      ALAN            9
```

I just want to know username = ALAN takes how many subject and how generate a new column to C become

```
ID     USERNAME        SUBJECT_ID    C
1      ALAN            1             1
2      ALAN            2             2
3      ALAN            3             3
4      ALAN            4             4
5      ALAN            5             5
7      ALAN            7             6
9      ALAN            9             7
```

The column is group by USERNAME and generate the row count.How should I query and generate C field?

The query I have tried, but I don't know how to generate "C"
SELECT ID,USERNAME,SUBJECT_ID,C FROM a WHERE USERNAME = "ALAN" GROUP BY SUBJECT_ID

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Row number in mysql, this way:

```
SELECT T1.*,@rownum := @rownum+1 as C
FROM TableName T1,(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
WHERE T1.Username LIKE '%ALAN%'
```

Result:

```
ID  USERNAME    SUBJECT_ID  C
-----------------------------
1   ALAN        1           1
2   ALAN        2           2
3   ALAN        3           3
4   ALAN        4           4
5   ALAN        5           5
7   ALAN        7           6
9   ALAN        9           7
```

Example in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3da90/1).

Comment: I was just reviewing the question actually, "try this" will be caught by the review queue deamon thingy, so I just mentioned it before it had a chance :)